# FullCalendar qTtip in Header

Tags: fullcalendar, tooltip, qtip2

Is there a way to attach a qTip (or bootstrap tooltip) to a FullCalendar header? I thought something like below would work but it doesn't.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fc-header-title').qtip({
        content: {
            text: '<img src="../Content/Images/EventLegend" />'
        }
    });
```

I've tried variations like td.fc-header-title, .fc-header, but nothing has worked.

- John C

Answer (score 1):

It would work fine that way - I just had to make sure this code came AFTER the fullcalendar defintion...